# Having trouble creating test Class for Schedulable class

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I'm having difficulties creating a test class to cover all my code.
My schedulable class is as follows

```
global class Scrum_Diario implements Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {

    Account accts = [SELECT Id, Name, OwnerID from account where Name='Scrum Diario The Influence' ];
    List<User> usuario = [Select Id, Alias from user where IsActive=True];    
        for (User us: usuario)
        {
            if(us.Alias!='EBenc'||us.Alias!='PEF'||us.Alias!='arodas'||us.Alias!='vecheve'){
            Task t= new task();
            t.Subject       =   'Scrum Diario';
            t.ActivityDate  =   Date.today();
            t.Description   =   'Llevar a cabo el Scrum diario antes de las 9:30';
            t.Status        =   'Open';
            t.WhatId        =   accts.Id;
            t.OwnerId       =   us.Id;
            t.Priority      =   'Normal';

            insert t;

            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code from your current test class and point where exactly the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

What I always do when testing classes that are schedulable is to never test the `execute` method itself.

Just create a public `execute` or `run` method, and call it directly from your code instead. You should be able to get 90%+ coverage without the headache from scheduling a job in Apex.

But if you are a perfectionist, **you can achieve 100% coverage** too. Scheduled classes can be tested using `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()` on your test method. When you schedule your class to run, say, in 5 minutes, when you call `Test.stopTest()` it will run despite being scheduled to run 5 minutes from now. You just need to remember to set up your test data as usual before scheduling the class and calling `stopTest`.

In your example, you'd need to have a test class that sets up some data (if needed), and then call the `System.schedule` **[method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm)**, which takes as parameters the following:

- a String that names the scheduled job (this name is what you'll see on Setup > Scheduled Jobs interface);
- a **[CRON expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)**, that represents when the class should run;
- an instance of the class you want to schedule;

Example:

```
System.schedule('Scrum Schedulable', '0 7 * * *', new Scrum_Diario());
```

Please also refer to the [**documentation on Apex Scheduler**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm).